# How to show Odds Ratio instead of Log Odds in bplot from lrm model (rms package)

Tags: r, interaction, rms

I'm using Frank Harrell's fantastic `rms` package to fit an lrm model with a continuous-by-continuous interaction. I want to show the interaction graphically.

To do this I'm using `bplot` which produces a nice 3d regression surface. However, the units on the Y-axis are in log-odds. I want to show Odds Ratio for the readers' ease of interpretation.

[image: 3d bplot of continuous-by-continuous interaction]

My code looks like this:

```
bplot(Predict(model,
              cont.var1=seq(5,110),
              cont.var2, np=50, ref.zero=TRUE),
      lfun=wireframe,
      adj.subtitle=FALSE, 
      drape=TRUE,
      color.key=FALSE,
      col.regions=terrain.colors(1000),
      asp=1,
      screen=list(z=-35, x=-60),
      ylabrot=48,
      xlabrot=-25,  
      main="Effect of cont.var2 on the relationship between cont.var1 and outcome")
```

I would be very grateful for any help!

Comment: Can you provide minimum data and the code for your model so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: Inside `Predict()` use `fun=plogis`.  Nice use of `col.regions`.  I recommend the use of the `perim` argument to cut out regions not supported by enough data points.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Thank you! did you mean the `fun=exp` argument? `fun=plogis` gives probabilities. 

Come to think of it, how would I change the scale on the Y axis to a logarithmic scale which I think is the appropriate way to plot ratios?

Comment: Whoops.  Yes `fun=exp` will give the odds.  Not so meaningful to plot odds ratios unless it's against a specific reference set of covariate values.  For your situation I'll bet probabilities are more interpretable.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Indeed it is adjusted for a set of covariates and they are set at their reference values. It would be nice to be able to show OR on log scale to help people appreciate the relative contribution of these important predictors. Same with 2d plots of spline-modeled continuous variables.

Comment: The linear predictor scale already shows the relative contributions (also do `plot(anova(fit))`.  ORs are fairly arbitrary.  But if you want to take total control of the situation use `contrast.rms` on a grid of values (varying 2 variables) against a covariate set for a vector of constants representing a reference subject.  You may have to run the 3-d graphics commands yourself.

Comment: @FrankHarrell Interestingly, fun=plogis gives very high probabilities. The lowest probability (observed at the reference values of the two interacted continuous covariates with all other covariates set at their lowest value) is 0.5. When I simply output the predicted probabilities using plogis(predict(model)), that is not the case (the lowest probabilities are in the order of 0.02). Any chance there is a bug with the fun=plogis option in Predict() ?

Comment: Try removing `ref.zero` when not using the linear predictor scale.  Also, if you still have trouble, examine the `Predict` output with and without `fun=`.